# marionette CompositeView access from templatehelpers

Tags: marionette

> ```
> MyModule.CompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
>     tagName: "div",
>     className: 'Liste',
>     id: idView,
>     itemView: MonModule.itemView,
>     itemViewContainer: "ul",
>     title: 'my title',
>     template: _.template('<%= header() %><ul></ul>'),
>     templateHelpers: {
>
>         header: function() {
>             var entete = _.template(collectionHeader, {nom: title});
>             return entete;
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

Hello,

I don't manage to get 'title' in templateHelpers/header from the composite view definition. The 'this' only gives me access to the templateHelpers itself while with an itemView i can access to the items.

Is possible to get this data in templateHelper or do I give up them in this case ?

thankyou

Comment: You should probably be using a Marionette Layout instead of CompositeView

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can get access to `this` by assigning a function to templatesHelpers, rather than an object.

e.g:

```
templateHelpers: function() {
  var that = this;

  return {
    header: function() {
      // code goes here
      // that refers to the view object
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you don't like the closure, you can reach the same result by using _.bind